# Make p:fileUpload advanced mode appear like simple mode

Tags: css, primefaces

i'm trying to display `FileUpload` with advanced mode and ajax feature, but  i wold like to make it appear like simple mode, which display just button with label name, 
this my facelet

```
  <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{scriptManagerForm.uploadSourceFile}" auto="true"
                                  skinSimple="true">
                        <f:attribute name="name" value="#{sourcefile.name}" />
     </p:fileUpload>
```

with this css

```
.fileupload-content{
                display: none;
            }
            .ui-fileupload .fileinput-button {
                background-color: rgba(142, 103, 64, 0.98);
            }
```

thank you,

Comment: post some code , i hope that you see what is done in `Primefaces` before asking this question

Comment: yes, i have seen primefaces doc, i will update the post to add some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to do this, but from a CSS perspective the code is below:

```
/*Hide the advanced buttons and progress*/
.ui-fileupload-upload, .ui-fileupload-cancel, .ui-fileupload-progress{
    display: none;
}

/*Move the file name and size of file onto same line*/
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar, .ui-fileupload-content{
    float: left;
}

/*Remove some of the margin from the file name to align correctly*/
.ui-fileupload-files{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Original

[image: Before]

After CSS

[image: After]